# Spring user authentication does not work after updating related document in Mongo Db

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm experiencing a rather weird behavior with Spring Security and Mongo Db.

I have a customer User entity that is persisted in Mongo:

```
@Document(collection = "user")
public class User {

  @Id
  private ObjectId id;

  private String username;

  ...
}
```

I implement a UserService that allows to persist such entities in a rather usual way:

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {
   @Override
   public void save(User user) {
     user.setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
     user.setAccountNonExpired(true);
     user.setAccountNonLocked(true);
     user.setCredentialsNonExpired(true);
     user.setEnabled(true);
     user.addRole(roleRepository.findByName("USER"));
     userRepository.save(user);
  }
  ...
}
```

I also have a SecurityService implementation:

```
@Service
public class SecurityServiceImpl implements SecurityService {
    @Override
    public void autologin(String username, String password) { ... }
}
```

And a UserDetailsService:

```
@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

   @Override
   @Transactional(readOnly = true)
   public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
       User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);
       if (user == null) {
          user = userRepository.findByEmail(username);
          if (user == null) {
             log.warn("Login attempt with unknown username");
             throw new UsernameNotFoundException("not found");
          }      
       }
       Set<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new HashSet<>();
       for (Role role : user.getRoles()) {
         grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName()));
}

return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(),
  user.isEnabled(), user.isAccountNonExpired(),
  user.isCredentialsNonExpired(), user.isAccountNonLocked(),
  grantedAuthorities);
```

}

In my controller, I have something like

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String login(HttpServletRequest request, Model model, String error, 
                  String logout, Principal principal) { ... }
```

This worked great. I can register users, login, logout, re-login. Info is persisted in Mongo and loaded properly. All seemed to be good, until I tried to implement reseting the password..

I implemented simple method in my UserServiceImpl class to perform this, but even by simply using the following implementation a rather weird behavior occurs:

```
@Override
public void updateUser(User user) {      
  userRepository.save(user);
}
```

After calling this method, if I log out, I can no longer login. I can re-start my spring-boot application, and still I cannot login.

This is odd because I can see that the JSON document in Mongo did not change. And this becomes crazy after I realized that if I manually edit the related document in Mongo (without performing any actual change, simply removing and adding the same character and saving it), then the login  works again!

If it helps:

MongoDB shell version: 3.2.13, spring boot 1.4.1.RELEASE

Any clue how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but I think you have missed a tiny big thing when updating user.
You encrypted password when you created a user

`user.setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));`

I am assuming your are updating password as well when updating password.
But there is no password encryption when updating user as i can see in your `updateUser` method (Unless you have encrypted password before calling this method).

And if I am correct then my advise to avoid update password while update user data and make different method to change password.